# NFS mount over network namespaces

Tags: nfs, network-namespaces

Is it possible to use NFS over Linux [network namespaces](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/7-namespaces/#lbAG)?

Does it even make sense? The only related thing in kernel source I found is is commit [7e3fcf61abde nfs: don't share mounts between network namespaces](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7e3fcf61abde92a895533b1c6932ad17e073a49c) which does not say much to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not using standard out-of-the-box (current) NFS mount tools.

Here is an example of some code that uses `setns` to do an NFS mount in the network (and mount) namespaces:

https://github.com/Netflix/titus-executor/blob/564624ebfe293681a4f599175efb7ab12f40508c/mount/mount.c

Comment: Thanks for interesting piece of code :). BTW `nsenter`: do you mean https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html (from [util-linux project](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/sys-utils/nsenter.c))? Because project has just [/apps/titus-executor/bin/titus-nsenter](https://github.com/Netflix/titus-executor/blob/master/inject/titus-nsenter.c) own implementation.

Comment: Whoops, no. I meant `setns`. Possibly the actual nsenter would work?

Answer (score 0):

Your question tackles two different namespaces, which are separate and unrelated at the kernel level as such ... until we throw in kernel NFS. Filesystem mounts are covered by mount namespace. My (limited) understanding now is that if you mount an NFS volume via network, processes joined to this mount namespace and joining/switching network namespaces make NFS mounts difficult: the same NFS mount could be connected to different NFS servers with the same IP address, depending on which process using this mount namespace is using which network namespace. This not only sounds messy, it will be. That's the reason why Linux drops NFS mounts for such processes.

So, in principle, mount and network namespaces are independent. However, things like NFS impose certain dependencies or restrictions. Please note that a user-space NFS would get bitten in such situations.